# Is there a performance difference between a Dropped Index and a Disabled Index, for a NON-Clustered Index

Tags: sql-server, nonclustered-index

I'm aware that there are substantial differences between Dropping and Disabling a ***CLUSTERED*** Index, but I want to know about ***NON***-CLUSTERED indexes.

And I'm aware that Disabling an Index retains the Metadata of the index definition, making it easier and lower maintenance to reinstate the Index afterwards.

But from a straight "Performance of INSERTs, UPDATEs and DELETEs" point-of-view ...

***Is there any performance difference between having Disabled a Non-Clustered Index, and having dropped it entirely.*** Either during the table edits, or for the CREATE vs the REBUILD afterwards?

Comment: Potentially helpful Jes Schultz article (on Brent Ozar), [What’s Better: Disabling vs. Dropping Indexes?](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/02/disabling-vs-dropping-indexes/)

Comment: @J.D. Yeah already found that article; it doesn't say anything at all about the performance differences (if any). It just gives you what the syntaxes are and mentions the metadata.

Answer (score 2):

[**As documented**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/disable-indexes-and-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15#Restrictions):

> The query optimizer does not consider the disabled index when creating query execution plans. Also, queries that reference the disabled index with a table hint fail.

The index is **completely ignored** for querying

> The index is not maintained while it is disabled.

So it doesn't appear in inserts, updates and deletes.

> You cannot create an index that uses the same name as an existing disabled index.

Not documented, but **you cannot drop columns** that the index depends on.